Drupal 8.9.19 to Drupal 9.0.0
I was trying to upgrade Drupal 8.9.19 to 9.0.0 using Composer via Plesk, and after running composer update, I get the following error:
"Update to the latest release of Drupal 9 for improved PHP 8 support, or use PHP 7.4. See the system requirements page for more information."
If I downgrade the PHP version to 7.4.33, it throws a 500 error and doesn’t allow me to do anything.
My MariaDB version is 10.11.8.
This is my composer.json file:
{
    "name": "drupal/recommended-project",
    "description": "Project template for Drupal 8 projects with composer following drupal/drupal layout",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
    "homepage": "https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal",
    "support": {
        "docs": "https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/index.html",
        "chat": "https://www.drupal.org/node/314178"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "composer/installers": "^1.9",
        "drupal/address": "^1.9",
        "drupal/admin_toolbar": "^2.2",
        "drupal/commerce": "^2.17",
        "drupal/commerce_variation_cart_form": "^1.2",
        "drupal/config_update": "^1.7",
        "drupal/ctools": "^3.3",
        "drupal/dropzonejs": "^2.3",
        "drupal/embed": "^1.2",
        "drupal/entity_browser": "^2.4",
        "drupal/entity_embed": "^1.2",
        "drupal/features": "^3.10",
        "drupal/field_group": "^3.1",
        "drupal/file_browser": "^1.3",
        "drupal/file_entity": "^2.0@beta",
        "drupal/fivestar": "^1.0@alpha",
        "drupal/flag": "^4.0@beta",
        "drupal/imce": "^1.8",
        "drupal/libraries": "^3.0@beta",
        "drupal/pathauto": "^1.7",
        "drupal/simplify_menu": "^2.1",
        "drupal/token": "^1.7",
        "drupal/video_embed_field": "^2.3",
        "drupal/votingapi": "^3.0@beta",
        "drupal/webform": "^5.9",
        "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": "9.0.0",
        "drupal/core-project-message": "9.0.0",
        "drupal/core-recommended": "9.0.0"

    },
    "conflict": {
        "drupal/drupal": "*"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "config": {
        "sort-packages": true,
        "platform": {
            "php": "7.4.33"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "drupal-scaffold": {
            "locations": {
                "web-root": "web/"
                
            }
        },
        "installer-paths": {
            "core": [
                "type:drupal-core"
            ],
            "libraries/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-library"
            ],
            "modules/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-module"
            ],
            "profiles/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-profile"
            ],
            "themes/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-theme"
            ],
            "drush/Commands/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-drush"
            ],
            "modules/custom/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-custom-module"
            ],
            "themes/custom/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-custom-theme"
            ]
        },
        "drupal-core-project-message": {
            "include-keys": [
                "homepage",
                "support"
            ],
            "post-create-project-cmd-message": [
                "<bg=blue;fg=white>                                                         </>",
                "<bg=blue;fg=white>  Congratulations, you’ve installed the Drupal codebase  </>",
                "<bg=blue;fg=white>  from the drupal/legacy-project template!               </>",
                "<bg=blue;fg=white>                                                         </>",
                "",
                "<bg=yellow;fg=black>Next steps</>:",
                "  * Install the site: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/install",
                "  * Read the user guide: https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/index.html",
                "  * Get support: https://www.drupal.org/support",
                "  * Get involved with the Drupal community:",
                "      https://www.drupal.org/getting-involved",
                "  * Remove the plugin that prints this message:",
                "      composer remove drupal/core-project-message"
            ]
        }
    }
}

The web is launched from within the web folder.
image
Additionally, I plan to update to Drupal 11. What is causing this issue?
Upgrading Drupal 8.9.19 to Drupal 9.0.0 with the goal of reaching Drupal 11.

Did composer actually update when you ran composer update? Did you run it with the with all dependancies option? You downgraded to PHP 7.4?? What PHP version was the site working on before? Have you checked the server log files for errors? Did you check the modules your using support Drupal 9? Before starting a major version upgrade, I always check with the upgrade status module first.
